# An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in SwyxAdminApp.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this.libManager = new LibManager();

here I am getting following Error
An exception of type `'System.TypeInitializationException'` occurred in **SwyxAdminApp.dll** but was not handled in user code
Additional information:

The type initializer for`'SWConfigDataClientLib.LibManager'`threw an exception.

```
private LibManager connect()
{
    ClassTrace.TraceSwitch.Level=TraceLevel.Verbose;
    this.libManager=new LibManager();
    this.libManager.WSBaseUrl="localhost";
    this.libManager.AuthenticationMode=SProxyObject.AuthenticationMode.UsernamePassword;
    this.libManager.Username= "Administrator@cloudphone.com";
    this.libManager.Password="SwyxCloudAlpha";
    return this.libManager;
}
```

Comment: It means your static constructor or static field initialization code throws an exception. How does it looks like?

Comment: Could you post the whole exception, including the error message, inner exceptions and the stack trace?